# Where should I look for missing ethernet terminals in my home?

Tags: wiring, ethernet

I just moved into a house. I found the central access for ethernet and everything is labeled. In some rooms i can find the ethernet outlets however in a couple I cant find them at all. I thought the cable could have been used for landline at first but the cable does not match and I also later found central access for landline. Is there somewhere it could be hidden; possibly behind a different plate? The ethernet central access has it labeled as being there. The only thing I can think of is it being mislabeled otherwise. I tried following the cable but it goes between the ceiling of the basement and main floor. I know nothing about any of this but kind of just guessing so far and would appreciate any help

Comment: One possibility, as low-voltage wiring doesn't require junction boxes, is that it was stubbed up into the walls for future use and never cut in. You might need an electronic tracer tool.

Comment: Or it may be behind blank cover plates (will look the same as electrical power  junction box cover plates, so be careful opening them if you do, and close the power ones back up without touching the interior wires at all.) Consider an [edit] to add some pictures of what you've got.

Comment: maybe the rooms aren't wired. labels on things when moving in have been wrong in the past...

Comment: isherwood has a good suggestion, you can purchase a toner (electronic tracer too)  for a relative low cost. They come in two parts, one part has a tone generator and some wires coming out that will you to clip on one of the wires. The second usually has a speaker which may or may not be part of the probe. You move this along the walls and when close you will hear a tone. Best to start from where the tone generator is and work your way to the other end. These are nice but they do have some faults and you may get several lines picking up the signal.

Comment: They could be/have been used for fixed network devices, such as wall/ceiling mounted wireless access points.